# Firebase_Auth_API Not Available on API 23

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-edittext, firebase-authentication

I have created an `EditText` I am using to capture a username and password to later store in Firebase. In an AVD running API 26, I have no issues. However, I recently created an AVD running API 23 and it is returning null on the 'loggedInAuth' variable I have created. From my understanding and research, this is a bug with Firebase. I am not sure if I can run this code on the API <= 23 or if it is only unique to emulators. Any help is appreciated:

```
    public void signup() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Signup");

    if (!validate()) {
        onSignupFailed();
        return;
    }


    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignupActivity.this,
            R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Creating Account...");
    progressDialog.show();

    mNewFirebaseUserEmail = _emailText.getText().toString();
    mNewFirebaseUserPassword = _passwordText.getText().toString();

    new Handler().postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // On complete call either onSignupSuccess or onSignupFailed
                    // depending on success
                    onSignupSuccess();
                    // onSignupFailed();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, 3000);
    onSignupSuccess();
}
```

onSignupSuccess()

```
public void onSignupSuccess() {
    signupButton.setEnabled(true);
    //not sure why this line is here
    setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
    //this line below actually creates the user in Firebase; does not write or save to any locations
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mNewFirebaseUserEmail, mNewFirebaseUserPassword)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                    FirebaseAuth loggedInAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    NULL BEING THROWN HERE
                    String ID = loggedInAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    //TODO: Update handling of display name
                    String displayName = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    HashMap<String, Object> id = new HashMap<>();
                    id.put("user_id", ID);
                    id.put("display_name", displayName);
                    mUserRef.child(ID).updateChildren(id);

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Authentication Failed with Email",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

BUG

```
 09-30 10:06:25.105 2456-2456/com.troychuinard.fanpolls E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.troychuinard.fanpolls, PID: 2456
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.troychuinard.fanpolls.SignupActivity$5.onComplete(SignupActivity.java:280)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: I am reading more about it, and it appears it has to do with the Firebase AUTH API not available on this device. Why would that be the case? is it because it is an emulator?

Comment: Yes, may be make a test in real device. What i am seeing that your `FirebaseAuth` is null.

Comment: So should I assume on a real device, anyone running API 23 will have this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and Check if user id is logged

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mNewFirebaseUserEmail, mNewFirebaseUserPassword)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Log.d(TAG, "user:"+user.getUid());
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
```